# How do I find out which string resource is currently assigned to the android:text property of a button view?

Tags: android, android-button

In my activity, I'm trying to make decisions based on the text displayed on a button.  I got it to work by doing:

```
if( startButton.getText() == "Stop" ) {
  startButton.setText("Start");
} else {
  startButton.setText("Stop");
}
```

But I'd like to do it in a way that is language independent, so by using the name of the string as it exists in strings.xml, i.e. "start_text" and "stop_text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29) and [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)
E.g.

```
if (startButton.getTag(R.id.state).equals("play")) {
   startButton.setText("Start");
   startButton.setTag(R.id.state, "stop");
} else {
   startButton.setText("Stop");
   startButton.setTag(R.id.state, "play");
}
```

Comment: I think this answer was more like what I was going for.  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to derive the name of a string that is present on a button's text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a toggle button.

```
<ToggleButton 
android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textOn="Vibrate on"
android:textOff="Vibrate off"
android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set the text from resource:
    startButton.setText(getString(R.string.stop));
It is better to define a selector for this in xml and not do that in code.